# How to declare a function parameter of type enum in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

This is the code I have right now:

```
extends Control

var _handles:Array = [];
var _handleSize:int = 10;
var _mouseOverHandleIndex = -1;
var _draggingHandleIndex = -1;



class Handle:
    enum MovementConstraint { Horizontal, Vertical, Both, None}

    var _movementConstraint: MovementConstraint = MovementConstraint.Both;
    var _position: Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO;
    
    func init(position:Vector2, movementConstraint: MovementConstraint):
        _position = position;
        _movementConstraint = MovementConstraint;
```

Godot parser is complaining about "The indentifier 'MovementConstraint' isn't a valid type (not a script or class), or couldn't be found on base self."

I have tried to move the enum outside (into he parent class space) but same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that a GDScript enum is a collection of constants (and a dictionary to access them, if the enum is named). So there are not really variables which type is the enum. Instead they are `int`. And yes, that also means Godot won't complain if set a value that is not from the enum you expect (you could add validation by defining a custom setter with `setget`).